# Adobe Animate/CreateJS - this.myMovieClip.stop(); not working - no error in console

Tags: createjs, adobe-animate

I'm just getting started in Adobe Animate/CreateJS. I'm trying to control the timeline of a movie clip ("myMovieClip") on frame 1 on the main stage, preventing it from playing. According to the documentation, this should work:

this.myMovieClip.stop();

But it does not... the movie "myMovieClip" clip plays immediately on test in the browser, and I'm not getting any error love from the console. It's as if the above line of code wasn't even there.

This seems pretty basic. What am I missing? I ultimately want to stop all movie clips on the main timeline as well as a large group of nested ones. If there's a single command that does this, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain this is related to a bug in the Adobe Animate output that makes MovieClip timelines not immediately available.

You can get around this by forcing an update before you try to access the children:

```
this.gotoAndStop(0); // Forces update
this.myMovieClip.stop();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well I'll be darned... that seems to do it, thanks! Can you expand a little... what exactly does this force the update of?

Comment: Another "solution" I've found is updating (manually) the version of CreateJS to the latest:

https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js

The default hosted library (when this option is checked in Publish Settings) is this ancient thing from 2015:

libs/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js

This is a less than ideal solution as it requires me to manually update the html file on every test. Animate CC is totally up to date, you would think that the hosted libraries would be updated as well, as opposed to continuing to use a CDN that is apparently from four years ago.

Comment: Agreed. We have been working with Adobe to try and get them to use 1.0.

Comment: I can't recall the cause exactly, but basically the timeline is not constructed initially, and so the children are not available. Calling a timeline method forces an update of the timeline. Cheers!