# HTML5 Canvas/CreateJS stop all nested movie clips?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, createjs, adobe-animate

Working with Adobe Animate/Canvas, I have one large movie clip containing dozens of small clips nested inside. I'd like to make sure all these clips are stopped at runtime, but I don't want to go through each one manually. Is there a way to stop all these clips programmatically from the main timeline?

I tried this:

`this.myBigContainingClip.stopAllMovieClips();`

But that doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely no `stopAllMovieClips` method :)
You can check out the docs here: https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MovieClip.html

Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484728/adobe-animate-createjs-this-mymovieclip-stop-not-working-no-error-in-cons/56496751#56496751), you will have to make sure the timeline is accessible. Note that this issue is recursive:

```
this.gotoAndPlay(0); // Update `this` timeline
this.myBigContainingClip.gotoAndPlay(0); // Update myMovieClip so you can access its timeline
```

Then you can iterate all the clips in the `myBigContainingClip` timeline, and tell them to stop

```
for (var i=0, l=this.myBigContainingClip.numChildren; i<l; i++) {
    this.myBigContainingClip.getChildAt(i).stop();
}
```

Note that this is pseudocode (untested), but it should work.

Happy coding!

Comment: Haha, thanks Lanny – in my defense, there is (was?) a `stopAllMovieClips` in AS3! Or so I heard. And, indeed, I'd actually gotten halfway there thanks to your answer to that other question. After that, completely lost. This works! Thanks once again!

Comment: Ha, it's been so long, I had forgotten! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
root=this;
const allmovieclips = root.children;
allmovieclips.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```